# Java Map with variable generics as values

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

So here's a slightly tricky question (for me).

I have a generic object. Call it MyObject. This object has a method which returns something of the type T:

```
public class MyObject<T>
{
    private T _t;

    public MyObject(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
    }

    //...

    public T get()
    {
        return _t;
    }
}
```

(Obviously my "MyObject" does a bit more but that's the gist).

Now, I want to have a map of this type:

```
Map<String, MyObject<?>> m = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to be able to fetch maps using some predefined string name, and these maps can be of any MyObject. For example, I could call:

```
m.put("map_1", new MyObject<String>("String"));
m.put("map_2", new MyObject<Integer>(new Integer(3));
m.put("map_3", new MyObject<Long>(new Long(5));
```

etc.

But - and here's the tricky part - I want the map to "remember" the parameterized type of MyObject when I fetch some value from the map. Using

```
m.get("map_1");
```

would return a

```
MyObject<Object>
```

type, since the map was defined as containing

```
MyObject<?>
```

values. Thus:

```
m.get("map_1").get() // <-- This is an Object, not a String!
```

What modification (if any) is possible, in order to be able to get the correct - full - information regarding the MyObject fetched object, such that invoking the last line (m.get("map_1")) would return a

```
MyObject<String>
```

Thanks :)

Amir.

Comment: There's nothing type safe you can do here.

Comment: There's a design example, Heterogeneous Type I think, in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java" that might meet your requirements.

Comment: What about Reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typesafe Heterogeneous Containers from Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* might work here.  Basically you add a `Class` object to represent the type.

```
public class MyObject<T>
{
    private T _t;
    private Class<T> type;

    public MyObject( Class<T> type, T t)
    {
        _t = t;
        this.type = type;
    }

    //...

    public T get()
    {
        return _t;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() { return type; }
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
public <T> T get( Map<String, MyObject<?>> map, String key, Class<T> type ) {
   return type.cast( m.get( key ).get() );
}
```

Which is safe and will compile, but will throw a runtime error if you get the type wrong.

(Note I didn't actually compile that, so I might have syntax errors floating around.  But most folks don't know how to use `Class` to cast objects.)

Comment: Hey, thank you - this looks very close to what I needed. A question though - as I understand, the "Class<T>" argument is like a "token" passing the type information, such that the generic method get <T> will know that we want to get a "T". So I could then simply pass a T object, no? It could be public <T> T get(Map<String, MyObject<?>> map, String key, T t){...}

Comment: I dont understand why we would store the Class as a separate field when each object contains its Class already.

Comment: @amirkr I think the distinction occurs when you want to pass an object that's part of a hierarchy.  For example, you actually pass in a `JLabel`, but you want its type to be `JComponent`.

Comment: @JoseMartinez The problem is the class type isn't really there.  It's erased.  It works in your example, but if you change your program at all, for example if the generic class is actually an interface not the class, your example won't work any more.  Finding a parameterized type through reflection is actually really tricky and difficult.

Comment: That doesn’t explain the value of that `type` field in `MyObject` at all—it isn’t used anywhere. The runtime check is performed using *parameter* `type` of the `get(Map<String,MyObject<?>>,String,Class<T>)` method, which would work exactly the same without the `type` field in `MyObject`. There might be scenarios where that pattern is useful, but here, it’s just an used additional field…

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class.

```
Class c = m.get("map_1").get().getClass();
if (String.class.equals(c)) {
    System.out.println("its a String");
}
```

Here is a full test.

```
public class GenericsTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, MyObject<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
        MyObject<String> obj = new MyObject<>("hello");

        map.put("greeting", obj);

        Class c = map.get("greeting").get().getClass();
        if (String.class.equals(c)) {
            System.out.println("its a String");
        }

    }

    static class MyObject<T> {

        T t;

        public MyObject(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        T get() {
            return t;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I don't only need to get the class, but to *act* on it - so if I got a String, the code "will know" its a string and be able to act on its methods. A response that might be helpful in that particular context was discussed in another comment here (I hope). Thanks for the effort, the "Class" object mechanism is still a bit vague for me and your code helped :)

Comment: I do not think you need to store the Class as a separate field when each Object already contains its Class.

Answer (score 0):

The type system only knows about types, not objects, and therefore can not distinguish `"key1"` from `"key2"`, because both are of type `String`.

If keys have different types, the easiest way is to encapsulate a weakly typed map, and use reflective casts to prove to the compiler the types are correct:

```
class Favorites {

    private Map<Class<?>,?> map = new HashMap<>();

    <V> V get(Class<V> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz));
    }

    <V> void put(Class<V> clazz, V value) {
        map.put(clazz, value);
    }
}

Favorites favs = new Favorites();
favs.put(String.class, "hello");
favs.put(Integer.class, 42);
favs.get(String.class).charAt(1);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. The keys have the same type (in my example - they are all strings), but the values have different types. What I wanted was to be able to infer the type directly when invoking the "get" method with some key - so, it I got a String the code "will know" (and allow me to use the string's methods), etc. The usage of Class is interesting though, as was also mentioned in another comment. Thanks for the input (pun intended) ;)